# jQuery Mobile Select Box flickering

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Android 2.3.4 OS Samsung S5570 POP device ...

I am working on an application using PhoneGap and jQueryMobile 1.0.1 ...

I have 2 select boxes in my application and options for each select box are around 7 to 10 ...

On click of Select box the options are opening fine but there is flickering of the select box if i try to close the select box or if i select an option from the select box ...

On closing or selecting an option from select box closes the options popup ... opens the popup again and then it finally closes ...

Then i thought of trying an native select box by mentioning data-native-menu="true" or data-role="none" in the select box ...

None of them worked .... So i was not able to implement the native select box ... I searched in the net ... I failed in getting the solution ...

So guys please help either in implementing an native select box or implementing an jquery mobile select box without flickering ... I already the below css ...

```
/* For smoother page transitions*/
.ui-page {
    -webkit-transform-style: flat;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
/* End smoother page transitions*/
```

I also tried the below css for native select box ... But no luck ...

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Please help me guys ...  Thanks in Advance ...!!!

Comment: Have you tried a custom non-native select found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html ?

Comment: help me if you got the solution for this problem as i am also facing the same.